# Path Address in RESTful Web Service using Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a question about [Restful Web Service in java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)

I am completely familiar with the information in the link and how to implement a Jersey service.

The path which I use is always something like this:

```
SERVER_ADDRESS/task/users/{username}/
```

SERVER_ADDRESS can be like `192.168.1.104:8080` and {username} is `@PathParam`

look at this address:

```
SERVER_ADDRESS/task/users/{username}/tasks?top=n
```

My question is about the end : `tasks?top=n`

I saw pretty much example with this kind of address at the end, but I don't know what is the usage of them in compare with for instance `@PathParam`.

How can we create such an idea in Jersey? 
And what is the usage of this kind of address?

Answer (score 4):

To get at `tasks`, your must wrap it in `{}` in the `@Path` and use a `@PathParam` to get it.

For `top=n` use a `@QueryParam("top") int` (if `int` is the type of `top`).

All this is described in the easy-to-read [JAX-RS Spec](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/), version 1.1.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give a short description in your answer when should we use `@QueryParam`? I will read the link as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Possible uses for `@QueryParam` are

- when you are passing some filters to the list you are goint to get back. These filters may be optonal and does fit as path params.
- Giving pagination limits like `start` and `offset` as a valid case.
- Passing a list of attributes that you need. For performance reasons you may not want the full response.

Comment: +1 for your help. Good to now. The third case which is `performance reasons` is what I am dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you to get more familiar with the `@QueryParam` - [Accessing query parameters using @QueryParam](https://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/accessing_query_parameters_using_queryparam)